# AWS lambda of python runtime 3.7 using layer of runtime 3.6

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have the following:
1.  AWS (lambda) layer of runtime python 3.6.
2. A lambda function of runtime python 3.7 that uses the above layer.

The layer packages it's modules in a zip with the required hierarhcy of `"python/lib/python3.6/site-packages"`.

The problem is that the lambda function does not find (i.e. fails to import) the layer modules, unless I explicitly do something like: `sys.path.append('/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages')`, which I feel is a workaround.

I would expect aws lambda framework to smoothly allow a 3.7 runtime to import modules from a layer with version < 3.7. (by adding the matching python path or by some other way).

Is there such a way that I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This layer hierarchy `python/lib/python3.6/site-packages` is not needed. You could just do `pip install xxx -t folder`, zip it, upload it, and set an `PYTHONPATH=/opt` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. If so, I could also just package it under 'python' and then it will work also without manipulating the python path. I tried to understand how to do it according to the guidelines, keeping some organization of code by it's compatible version.